# jQuery onchange not working for multiple element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, onchange

I am adding multiple text box element with the same class.

It's not working in my project, for demo purpose i added the code to `(http://jsfiddle.net/8gbvd/)`

Its working there how to debug this issue

Thank you

Comment: Does the navigator inspector return errors ?

Comment: Well if the fiddle is working, then you got a working example to compare your code to... the problem is most probably in the differences... My first guess would be that you're actually adding those textboxes dynamically with javascript, while they're hard-coded in you jsfiddle, Am I right ?

Comment: @Jahnux73 no navigator inspector didn't return errors

Comment: @Bartdude yes its added dynamically to the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your textboxes are dynamically added to the page, you need to use delegated events. So

DON'T DO THIS :

```
jQuery('.qtyBox').change(
    function(){
         alert(jQuery(this).val());
    });
```

BUT DO THIS INSTEAD :

```
jQuery('#priceRuleTable').on('change','.qtyBox',
    function(){ 
        alert(jQuery(this).val());
    });
```

cfr [this page](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for a more detailed explanation on event delegation.

note that if you want to perform an action each time a key is pressed (and not when the user leaves the textbox , you can use the event `input` instead of `change`

Answer (score 0):

If you have same class for multiple select elements and you want to get selected value, only for the changed element, then you can do something as below:

```
$('#priceRuleTable').on('change', '.qtyBox', function(){
    //to check only selected item is being triggered add css, you can remove it later
    $(this).parent().css("border", "2px solid red");
    //you should get value of the changed select element 
    var v = $(this).parent().find("option:selected").text();
    console.log(v);
});
```